# Why has server socket to be opened before client socket?

Tags: java, android, sockets, connection, client-server

I used socket programming in Java. I connected one pc and android tablet. Server is pc , client is tablet. When i start firstly tablet, socket cannot be connected. However, when i start firstly pc , socket can be connected. Why is this so ? where is the problem ?

Pc code:

`

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ServerSocket listener = null;
                    Socket socket = null;
                    System.out.println("Opened");
                    try {
                        listener = new ServerSocket(1515);

                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
                    }
                    String answer = null;

                    while(true)
                    {

                        try {
                            socket = listener.accept();

                            DataInputStream input =
                                    new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                            answer = input.readInt()+ " ";
                            answer = answer + input.readInt();
                            input.close();
                            dName.setText(answer);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    }


                }
            });
            t.start();
```

`

Tablet code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean check = false;
    while(!check)
    {
        try {
            check = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { (byte) 192, (byte) 168, 2, 86 }).isReachable(1000);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    while(!socket.isConnected()){
        try {
            socket.connect(sockaddr, 1000);
            //  DataInputStream input =
            //          new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            //  int result = input.readInt();
            //  if(result == -2)
            //  {
            //      MainActivity.MainAct.StartUpdateActivity();
            //  }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //text.setText(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }finally{

        }
    }
```

EDIT: The firt while , the check condition using InetAddress.isReachable , is TRUE for all time. That means isReachable is false for all time. When i remove it , the connection can be established . However , the question still remains the same.

Comment: Just get rid of the isReachable() call. It's pointless. The socket connect will succeed or fail. That's all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation for `isConnected` : [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected%28%29)

```
Returns the connection state of the socket.
Note: Closing a socket doesn't clear its connection state, which means this method will return true for a closed socket (see isClosed()) if it was successfuly connected prior to being closed.
```

So your

```
while(!socket.isConnected()){
```

line is only working until first successful connection.

**Update**

Seems [EJP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005184/why-has-server-socket-to-be-opened-before-client-socket/24005317#24005317) is also true, even if your `while(!socket.isConnected()){` works correctly, you can't establish a connection using an already closed socket, you will end up `java.net.SocketException: Socket closed`. So you have to re-create the socket everytime.

```
    while (!shouldIStop()/*some condition in case if you ever want to stop*/) {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        try {
            socket.connect(yourAddress, 1000);
            //do something...
        } catch (IOException e) {

        } finally {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

A client socket is something that connects to a server.
If there is no server running, there is nothing for it to connect to.

A server socket simply accepts connections.

Comment: No no. I mean that , when i start firtly tablet then pc, socket cannot be establieshed. when reverse is done, i mean first pc then tablet, it works. For both conditions, pc and tablet are opened.

Comment: @user14570: Huh? You still need to start the server first.

Comment: i could not understand this. :S may be port cannot be opened. I tried most times . first tablet then pc. However it did not work :( i will try again

Comment: You can't connect to a server that isn't running.

Comment: you mean that have i start first server side , pc side ? tablet may be started firstly.

Comment: Yes.  Again, you can't connect unless there is something to connect to.

Comment: If the server is not running, the client cannot connect to it. The client will have to keep trying periodically.  If the server is then  started, the client will be able to connect on its next attempt.

Answer (score 2):

A server socket is listening for a client to make a connection (like someone waiting to answer the telephone). If the client attempts to connect (places a call) and there's no one listening (no one answers the call), there's nothing for the client to do, so it gives up and throws an exception (hangs up the phone).  Try to connect again (redial the phone) at a later time.

Comment: It is true. But i used while(true) for server side. When it gives error, it will try again and again and again. It is also valid for client. It has also while like true option

Answer (score 1):

You can't reconnect a socket after a failed connection attempt, as the exceptions would have told you. You have to close it and create a new one.

Comment: first time it works , after that it fails.

Comment: @EJP I don't think that is true. There is no mention for it at the documentation and I don't see any IllegalStateException. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress,%20int)

Comment: @Onur I'm not guessing. I didn't say anything about `IllegalStateException.` In fact you get a `SocketClosedException`, so you don't even have to close it yourself, just create a new one. I suggest you try it before you post again.

Comment: @EJP Yes, you are right, sorry. I updated my answer. Thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: @Onur Best not to comment on things you don't know about.